# Convert relative path to full URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, path

My main domain is http://redrocksoftware.com.au. i have an relative path to a file like /PDF/myfile.pdf

I need to convert this relative path into full URL. something like below.

http://redrocksoftware.com.au/PDF/myfile.pdf

i tried below but did not worked

VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("/PDF/myfile.pdf")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
string FullUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + "/PDF/MyFile.pdf"
```

It works in asp.net, I'm not sure about MVC, but it should work too.

Comment: This mostly works, but be careful about non-default ports. If you run this locally, for example, with your development site running on something like `localhost:12345`, this will only give you `http://localhost/PDF/MyFile.pdf`, which obviously won't work.

Comment: Close, but you should use `Request.Url.Authority` not `Request.Url.Host` to handle non-standard ports and urls that require username and passwords.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to combine an absolute URI and a relative path:

```
Uri absolute = new Uri("http://redrocksoftware.com.au/");
Uri result = new Uri(absolute, "/PDF/MyFile.pdf");
// result == {http://redrocksoftware.com.au/PDF/MyFile.pdf}
```

Comment: I think that @chamara was rather asking how to retrieve the absolute url, not how to add two strings together and turn it to Uri.

Comment: @KamilT: So, just use `Uri absolute = new Uri(Request.RawUrl);`.

Answer (score 8):

The following extension method worked for me:

```
 public static class Extensions
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Turns a relative URL into a fully qualified URL.
    /// (ie http://domain.com/path?query) 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <param name="relativeUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetFullUrl(this HttpRequest request, string relativeUrl) {
        return String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
                        request.Url.Scheme,
                        request.Url.Authority,
                        VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativeUrl));
    }
 }
```

Use it as follows:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.GetFullUrl("~/MyOtherPage.aspx");
```

Works with virtual directories too, and you dont need MVC.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` includes the virtual directory, which is omitted from all the other answers. It's not always the case that your web application is hosted at the highest level of your domain, and you're shooting yourself in the foot if you don't account for the possibility now.

Answer (score 0):

Return new System.Uri(Page.Request.Url, ResolveClientUrl("~/relative/path.aspx")).AbsoluteUri